# adjusting midpoint in scale_colour_gradient2()

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm generating a heatmap of p-values using the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(res, aes(x=group, y=variable)) +
geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = "yellow") +
scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red", name="p-value") +
ggtitle("title") +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90)) +
labs(x="maoa",y="maob")

print(p)
```

and would like to use

```
d + scale_colour_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "black", high = "green", midpoint = 0.05, guide = "legend")
```

to add a midrange color and adjust the midpoint. However, this outputs results without the colors I input nor the midpoint. Any suggestions?

Comment: As you are using fill=value in aes() you should use scale_fill_gradient2() not scale_colour.. and also you should use scale_fill.. only once (you already have scale_fill.. in your code)

Comment: I would be replacing scale_fill with scale_colour. Is there a way to adjust midpoint using scale_fill_gradient?

Comment: @soosus Just use scale_fill_gradient2() instead of scale_fill_gradient() and set all parameters you need (mid,low, and so on)

Comment: @Didzis Elferts I've switched to using scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "black", high = "green", midpoint = 0.05, space = "rgb", guide = "legend") but I get an output with a midpoint around .5 and a color scale from dark to light green :/

Comment: No one will be able to help further unless you provide a reproducible example.